# python3/logging: Optionally write to more than one stream

Tags: python-3.x, logging

I'm successfully using the `logging` module in my python3 program to send log messages to a log file, for example, `/var/log/myprogram.log`. In certain cases, I want a subset of those messages to also go to `stdout`, with them formatted through my `logging.Logger` instance in the same way that they are formatted when they go to the log file.

Assuming that my logger instance is called `loginstance`, I'd like to put some sort of wrapper around `loginstance.log(level, msg)` to let me choose whether the message only goes to `/var/log/myprogram.log`, or whether it goes there and also to `stdout`, as follows:

```
# Assume `loginstance` has already been instantiated
# as a global, and that it knows to send logging info
# to `/var/log/myprogram.log` by default.
def mylogger(level, msg, with_stdout=False):
    if with_stdout:
        # Somehow send `msg` through `loginstance` so
        # that it goes BOTH to `/var/log/myprogram.log`
        # AND to `stdout`, with identical formatting.
    else:
        # Send only to `/var/log/myprogram.log` by default.
        loginstance.log(level, msg)
```

I'd like to manage this with one, single `logging.Logger` instance, so that if I want to change the format or other logging behavior, I only have to do this in one place.

I'm guessing that this involves subclassing `logging.Logger` and/or `logging.Formatter`, but I haven't figured out how to do this.

Thank you in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to do it. It simply requires that I use a `FileHandler` subclass and pass an extra argument to `log()` ...

```
class MyFileHandler(logging.FileHandler):
    def emit(self, record):
        super().emit(record)
        also_use_stdout = getattr(record, 'also_use_stdout', False)
        if also_use_stdout:
            savestream = self.stream
            self.stream = sys.stdout
            try:
                super().emit(record)
            finally:
                self.stream = savestream
```

When instantiating my logger, I do this ...

```
logger = logging.getLogger('myprogram')
logger.addHandler(MyFileHandler('/var/log/myprogram.log'))
```

Then, the `mylogger` function that I described above will look like this:

```
def mylogger(level, msg, with_stdout=False):
    loginstance.log(level, msg, extra={'also_use_stdout': with_stdout})
```

This works because anything passed to the `log` function within the optional `extra` dictionary becomes an attribute of the `record` object that ultimately gets passed to `emit`.